# Looking for big list of shortening service websites

Tags: html, url-shorteners

Does anybody know where to get list of working long2short service websites? The bigger the better - I need at least 100 of them.

Comment: Why do you need more than one?

Answer (score 2):

Not all URL shortener services are reliable. Check [this comparison of popular URL shortener services](http://searchengineland.com/analysis-which-url-shortening-service-should-you-use-17204) for their pros & cons. ([Here](http://notlong.com/links/)'s a shorter comparison by notlong.)

Google also has their own [Goo.gl](http://goo.gl) shortener service with an [API](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/01/google-url-shortener-gets-api.html). [Pingdom](http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/10/29/is-goo-gl-really-the-fastest-url-shortener-chart/) found Goo.gl to be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

The list at http://hjacob.com/blog/2009/07/url-shortener-redirects/ looks pretty good.  There are still a lot of dead links.  Here are the listed URLs that responded `200 OK` (which doesn't necessarily mean it is still working as a url shortening service):

- 03e.de - http://03e.de/
- 6url - http://6url.com/
- A.gd - http://a.gd/
- Bit.ly - http://bit.ly/
- Chilp.it - http://chilp.it/
- Cli.gs - http://cli.gs/
- Decent URL - http://decenturl.com/
- Doiop - http://doiop.com/
- Dot.TK - http://dot.tk/
- DwarfURL - http://www.dwarfurl.com/
- Fhurl - http://fhurl.com/
- Good.ly - http://good.ly/
- HotRedirect - http://www.hotredirect.com/
- Idek.net - http://idek.net/
- Jaze Redirect Services - http://iscool.net/
- Kl.am - http://kl.am/
- Korta ner din url - http://www.x.se/
- Krz.ch - http://krz.ch/
- Lil.io - http://lil.io/
- Linkbun.ch - http://linkbun.ch/
- LinksPreadeR (l.pr) - http://l.pr/
- Metamark - http://metamark.net/
- Migre - http://migre.me/
- MooURL - http://moourl.com/
- Nutshellurl - http://nutshellurl.com/
- QR.cx - http://qr.cx/
- Redirx - http://redirx.com/
- SN.im / Snurl.com - http://sn.im/
- Shorl - http://shorl.com/
- Short URL - http://url.lotpatrol.com/
- Short links - http://shortlinks.co.uk/
- ShortURL - http://www.shorturl.com/
- Shorty - http://get-shorty.com/
- Shrinkurl - http://shrinkurl.us/
- SimURL - http://simurl.com/
- Starturl - http://www.starturl.com/
- TightURL - http://tighturl.com/
- TinyURL - http://tinyurl.com/
- Tr.im - http://tr.im/
- Trim.li - http://trim.li/
- Tweetburner.com - http://twurl.nl/
- Twi.bz - http://twi.bz/
- U28.de - http://u28.de/
- URL.co.uk - http://url.co.uk/
- URL.ie - http://url.ie/
- URLBee - http://urlbee.com/
- URLBorg - http://urlborg.com/
- URLShort - http://urlshort.com/
- URLcut - http://urlcut.com/
- UX.lv - http://ux.lv/
- VDirect - http://www.vdirect.com/
- Webalias - http://www.webalias.com/
- Yep.it - http://yep.it/
- Z.pe - http://z.pe/
- aPu.sh - http://apu.sh/
- adjix aka. ad.vu - http://www.adjix.com
- arm.in - http://arm.in/
- awe.sm - http://awe.sm
- awe.sm - http://create.awe.sm/
- binged.it - http://binged.it
- budurl - http://budurl.com/
- daa.li - http://daa.li/
- dot.tk - http://dot.tk
- easyURL - http://easyurl.net/
- fb.me - http://fb.me
- goo.gl - http://goo.gl/
- goo.la - http://goo.la/
- ho.io - http://ho.io/
- i2h.de - http://i2h.de/
- is.gd - http://is.gd/
- j.mp - http://j.mp/
- myurl - http://myurl.in/
- ne1.net - http://ne1.net/
- notlong - http://notlong.com/
- su.pr - http://su.pr/
- to.vg - http://to.vg/
- turo.us - http://turo.us/
- tweak.tk - http://tweak.tk
- twt.tl - http://twt.tl/
- u.nu - http://u.nu/
- unfake.it - http://unfake.it/
- wp.me - http://wp.me

For some reason, [my favorite](http://www.urlshorteningservicefortwitter.com/) wasn't listed.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys
import urlparse
import urllib

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

filename = 'url_shortner_redirects.html'
source = 'http://hjacob.com/blog/2009/07/url-shortener-redirects/'
page = urllib.urlopen(source).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
links = soup.findAll('a')

good_links = []
# Some links hang forever - set a timeout of 5 seconds
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
for link in links:
  # Look for the links with rel=external
  if link.get('rel', '') == 'external' and link.get('title','') != '':
    # Only the links with no path are url shortners - the rest are articles
    url = urlparse.urlparse(link['href'])
    if len(url.path) < 2:
      name = link.string.strip()
      href = link['href']
      try:
        x = urllib.urlopen(href)
        if x.code in [200]:
          print >> sys.stderr, '%s is responding' % href
          good_links.append((name, href))
        elif x.code in [403, 404, 503]:
          print >> sys.stderr, '%s is dead (%d)' % (href, x.code)
        else:
          print >> sys.stderr, "Unknown code %d in %s" % (x.code, href)
          x.close()
      except IOError:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Connection refused for %s" % href

# Print in stack exchange markdown
unique_links = sorted(list(set(good_links)))
print '\n'.join(['* %s - <%s>' % (name, href) for name, href in unique_links])
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search found [this](http://blog.go2.me/2009/01/exhausting-review-of-link-shorteners.html). Took about 10 seconds to find.

Comment: most of them is not working - it's 2 yo list

Comment: Did you [Google this](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=list+of+url+shorteners)? There are plenty of lists out there.